# jsonwebtoken error No default engine was specified and no extension was provided

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js, react-native

Hi i am trying to use passportjs and jsonwebtoken for my android app's authentication, but when i try to generate a token as the user login and test the api with postman it response error:

> No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
>       at new View (C:\newApp\awesomeProject\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:61:11)
>       at Function.render (C:\newApp\awesomeProject\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
>       at ServerResponse.render (C:\newApp\awesomeProject\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
>       at C:\newApp\awesomeProject\server\app.js:68:9
>       at Layer.handle_error (C:\newApp\awesomeProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
>       at trim_prefix (C:\newApp\awesomeProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
>       at C:\newApp\awesomeProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (C:\newApp\awesomeProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (C:\newApp\awesomeProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at Layer.handle_error (C:\newApp\awesomeProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:67:12)
>       at trim_prefix (C:\newApp\awesomeProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
>       at C:\newApp\awesomeProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (C:\newApp\awesomeProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (C:\newApp\awesomeProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at Layer.handle_error (C:\newApp\awesomeProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:67:12)
>       at trim_prefix (C:\newApp\awesomeProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)

This is my code:

routes.js

```js
var express  = require('express'),
    router   = express.Router(),
    passport = require('passport');
    todo     = require('./controller/todo.js'),
    user     = require('./controller/user.js');

router.get('/', user.isLoggedIn, user.userLogin);

router.get('/loginFailure', function(req, res, next){
 res.send("Invalid username or password");
})

router.get('/login', user.isLoggedOut);

//AUTH routes
router.post('/registration', user.userRegister);
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                                    failureRedirect: '/loginFailure' }));
router.get('/logout', user.userLogout)

//Application routes
router.post('/createUser', user.createUser);
router.get('/getUsers', user.getUsers);
router.get('/getUser/:id', user.getUser)
router.put('/updateUser/:id', user.updateUser);
router.delete('/deleteUser/:id', user.deleteUser);

router.get('/todoList', todo.getTodoList);
router.get('/detail/:id', todo.getTodo);
router.post('/createTodo', todo.createTodo);
router.put('/updateTodo/:id', todo.updateTodo);
router.delete('/deleteTodo/:id', todo.deleteTodo);

module.exports = router;
```

and in the controller, user.js:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
      userModel  = require('../model/User.js'),
      provider   = require('../provider/provider');

var passport              = require('passport');
    // localStrategy         = require('passport-local'),
    // passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose'),
    // expressSession        = require('express-session');


module.exports.userRegister = function(req, res, next){
  var Content = {
      "username": req.body.username,
      "password": req.body.password
   }

  var validate = provider.validateParam(Content);

  if (!validate.status){
    var objReturns = provider.setDataReturn(false, 'parram is null', validate.message);
        res.json(objReturns);
  } else {
      userModel.register(new userModel({ "username": req.body.username }), req.body.password, (err, contentCreated) => {
      if (err) {
                  var objReturns = provider.setDataReturn(false, 'registered failed', err);
                  res.json(objReturns);
          } else {
                  passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
                    console.log("authenticate works");
                  })
                  var objReturns = provider.setDataReturn(true, 'registered successful', contentCreated);
                  res.json(objReturns);
          }
      })
  }
}

module.exports.userLogin = function(req, res, next){
  if(req.user){
    var objReturns = provider.setDataReturn(true, 'login successful', req.user);
    res.json(objReturns);
  } else {
    var objReturns = provider.setDataReturn(false, 'log in failed', req.user);
    res.json(objReturns);
  }
}
  
module.exports.userLogout = function(req, res, next){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/login');
}

module.exports.isLoggedOut = function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.user){
    var objReturns = provider.setDataReturn(true, 'logout successful', req.user);
    res.json(objReturns);
  } else {
    var objReturns = provider.setDataReturn(false, 'logout failed', req.user);
    res.json(objReturns);
  }
}

module.exports.isLoggedIn = function(req, res, next){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    return next();
  } 
  console.log("isLoggedIn triggered, did not authenticate");
    res.redirect('/login');
}

module.exports.createUser = function(req, res, next){
 var Content = {
      "username": req.body.username,
      "password": req.body.password
   }

   //console.log(Content);
  var validate = provider.validateParam(Content);

  if (!validate.status){
   var objReturns = provider.setDataReturn(false, 'parram is null', validate.message);
        res.json(objReturns);
 } else {
    userModel.createUser(Content, (err, contentCreated) => {
   if (err) {
                 var objReturns = provider.setDataReturn(false, 'created failed', err);
                 res.json(objReturns);
         } else {
                 var objReturns = provider.setDataReturn(true, 'created successful', contentCreated);
                 res.json(objReturns);
         }
    })
 }
}

module.exports.getUsers = function(req, res, next) {
    
 userModel.getUsers((err, userFound) => {
    if (err) {
            var objReturns = provider.setDataReturn(false, err + '', err);
            res.json(objReturns);
        } else {
            var objReturns = provider.setDataReturn(true, 'successful', userFound);
            res.json(objReturns);
        }
    });
}

//Get todo by Id
module.exports.getUser = function(req, res, next) {
  var Content = {
      "_id": req.params.id
   };

   
  var validate = provider.validateParam(Content);

  if (!validate.status){
    var objReturns = provider.setDataReturn(false, 'parram is null', validate.message);
        res.json(objReturns);
  } else {
      userModel.getUserById(Content, (err, userFound) => {
      if (err) {
                  var objReturns = provider.setDataReturn(false, err+ '', err);
                  res.json(objReturns);
          } else {
                  var objReturns = provider.setDataReturn(true, 'successful', userFound);
                  res.json(objReturns);
          }
      })
  }
}

...
   //Update User and delete User code below
```

This is the provider.js file:

```js
const config = require('../config.js'); //ket noi db
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports.deletePropertyOBject = function(myObject, property) {
    var obj = myObject;
    delete obj[property];
    // console.log(obj);
    return obj;
}

module.exports.setDataReturn = function(status = '', message = '', data = {}) {


    *// const token = jwt.sign(data, 'superSecret', { expiresIn: config.tokenTime });*
     
    IF I UNCOMMENTED THIS IT WOULD REPORT THE ERROR

    var objReturn = {
        "success": status,
        "message": message,
        'data': data,
    };
    return objReturn;
}

module.exports.createToken = function(user) {
        var token = jwt.sign(user, 'superSecret', { expiresIn: config.tokenTime });
        return token;
}
    //xac thuc token
module.exports.verifyToken = function(req, res, next) {
    next();
    // var bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization'];;

    // if (typeof(bearerHeader) !== 'undefined') {
    //     var bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ');
    //     var bearerToken = bearer[0];
    //     jwt.verify(bearerToken, 'superSecret', function(err, authData) {
    //         if (err) {
    //             res.sendStatus(403);
    //         } else {
    //             next();
    //         }
    //     });
    // } else {
    //     res.sendStatus(403);
    // }
}

module.exports.validateParam = function(obj) {
    var output = {
        status: true,
        message: []
    };

    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {

        if (typeof value === "undefined") {
            output.message.push(key);
            output.status = false;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Thank you for you help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

req.user is a mongoose object therefore when use it in jwt.sign(), which obviously cause the problem, we have to turn that object into json replace the user in jwt.sign(user) with use.toJSON(). That will fix the problem